# Throwing error relu_(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple while printing summery in pytorch sequential model?

Tags: pytorch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchsummary import summary

feature_extractor_1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.GRU(8, 64, num_layers=2, batch_first=True),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.Linear(64, 64),
        nn.ReLU(True)
    ).to('cuda')

summary(feature_extractor_1, input_size=(2500,8), device='cuda')
```

ERROR:

```
~/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py in forward(self, input)
    100 
    101     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 102         return F.relu(input, inplace=self.inplace)
    103 
    104     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

~/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in relu(input, inplace)
   1294         return handle_torch_function(relu, (input,), input, inplace=inplace)
   1295     if inplace:
-> 1296         result = torch.relu_(input)
   1297     else:
   1298         result = torch.relu(input)

TypeError: relu_(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple
```

i want to print summery of my sequential model using torchsummary. I've seen couple of example doing exactly same as i did but in my case it's not working. I'm doing something wrong. please help.

Answer (score 3):

RNN built-in layers such as [`nn.GRU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) return a *tuple* of tensors:

> Outputs: `output`, `h_n`

For this reason you can't have this type of layer in a `nn.Sequential` pipeline. A possible workaround is to build a custom module to combine the recurrent neural network with the fully connected layer:

```
class FeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gru = nn.GRU(8, 64, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.ReLU(True),
                                nn.Linear(64, 64), 
                                nn.ReLU(True))
    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = self.gru(x)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

Then,

```
>>> summary(FeatureExtractor(), input_size=(2500,8), device='cuda')
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
               GRU-1  [[-1, 2500, 64], [-1, 2, 64]]               0
              ReLU-2             [-1, 2500, 64]               0
            Linear-3             [-1, 2500, 64]           4,160
              ReLU-4             [-1, 2500, 64]               0
================================================================
Total params: 4,160
Trainable params: 4,160
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.08
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 152.59
Params size (MB): 0.02
Estimated Total Size (MB): 152.68
----------------------------------------------------------------
```